# Rails Multiple Select boxes: Injecting default values from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-select

I currently have a multiple select box in a rails form that looks like this:

```
= select_tag :in_all_tags, options_from_collection_for_select(Tag.where(:project_id => @project.id), :id, :name, @in_all_tags_param), { :id => "tags", :tabindex => "3", "data-placeholder" => "Choose Tags", :multiple => "multiple" }
```

Where

```
@in_all_tags_param = params[:in_all_tags]
```

The problem is, `@in_all_tags_param` will only populate the select form with the last value from `params[:in_all_tags]`. So, if the url string reads `in_all_tags=5&in_all_tags=8`, the pre-selected value in the multiple select will only be 8.

From what I understand, the way around this is to append `[]` to the field name for multiple params, so that `:in_all_tags` becomes `in_all_tags[]`

BUT, when I try this, submitting the form returns:

```
Expected type :default in params[:in_all_tags], got Array
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `:name` element to the same hash with `:multiple => true` in it. So I use something similar for Genres on an app for mine and I do `{ :multiple => true, :name => "lesson[genre_ids][]" }`. The name has to be `model[attribute][]`.